# A new CHAMPion - Compressed Hash-Array Mapped Prefix-tree in C

Tags: c, multithreading, immutability

I implemented an immutable hash map in C, as described in [this paper](https://michael.steindorfer.name/publications/oopsla15.pdf). First, my design goals:

- plug-and-playable: compile with `gcc -O3 -std=c11 champ.c`, `#include "champ.h"`, ready to use
- `#define` Key and value types to suit your needs: see *Using it as a "`champ<string,int>`"* below
- Provide reference counting as the default heap policy, but make it easy enough to modify the source to use your own strategy
- thread safety: persistent collections really start to take off in a multithreaded environment, which is where I intend to use this
- cache locality: The abovementioned paper puts a lot of focus on improving cache locality, so I wanted to at least match that

Further below you can see what I have so far. It does what it's supposed to, i'm pretty confident that it's correct and stable, I have written extensive tests (84% coverage, up to 98% planned), valgrind comes up clean. However, I still have some big question marks/insecurities:

- Is the interface well designed?
- Is my use of `const` sensible?

  - In particular: what about taking keys/values params as `const`, which really only has any significance when they are actually pointers.
- Is there any value in hiding the `struct champ` implementation if I intend to distribute it as source code anyway?
- How can I test the implementation (a fairly critical aspect of library development) without subverting/undermining the interface?
- Is my strategy for dealing with memory management requirements sensible? (making the source accessible and easy to hack)
- Should I use more `typedef`'s? Maybe instead of `CHAMP_VALUE_T`?

Of course, any feedback is desired. I really only have a grasp of C semantics, but little experience in developing large scale projects.

Lastly, a short breakdown of the biggest "gotchas":

- This is a hash trie with a branching factor of 32. It takes a key-value-pair, computes the key's hash (`uint32_t`), and looks at the five least significant bits, interpreting them as the index in the root node of the trie (2^5 == 32).
- If the node already contains an entry at that index, but with an unequal key, the current entry and the new key-value-pair are "pushed down". Their hashes are shifted to the right by 5 bits, and the five next least significant bits are used to determine the entries' index in the next level, and the process starts again.
- This is a persistent data structure, so instead of modifying a node, a copy of that node gets created and modified, which in turn is then inserted into a copy of it's parent node, and so on, until a new root node gets created and inserted into a new hash map.
- There's 7 "levels" of nodes (32 / 5 = 6.4, the last layer only hash 2 bits of variance). In case of a hash collision - which only happens if the *entire* hash is equal, so it *should* happen less often than with conventional hash tables - an 8th layer is created. At that level only a special kind of node gets created (`struct collision_node`), and that special kind of node only gets created at that level. Therefore I'm using `shift >= HASH_TOTAL_WIDTH` to determine whether I'm dealing with a regular or a collision node, so I don't have to implement some sort of dynamic dispatch polymorphism.

#### champ.h:

```c
/*
 * MIT License
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2020 Samuel Vogelsanger <vogelsangersamuel@gmail.com>
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
 * copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
 * SOFTWARE.
 */
#ifndef CHAMP_CHAMP_H
#define CHAMP_CHAMP_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#ifndef DEBUG_PRINT
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DBG 1
#else
#define DBG 0
#endif
#define DEBUG_PRINT(fmt, ...) \
            do { if (DBG) fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG: champ: " fmt, __VA_ARGS__); } while (0)
#endif

#ifndef CHAMP_KEY_T
#define CHAMP_KEY_T void*
#endif

#ifndef CHAMP_VALUE_T
#define CHAMP_VALUE_T void*
#endif

/**
 * These are mostly for convenience
 */

#define CHAMP_HASHFN_T(name) uint32_t (*name)(const CHAMP_KEY_T)
#define CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(name) int (*name)(const CHAMP_KEY_T left, const CHAMP_KEY_T right)
#define CHAMP_ASSOCFN_T(name) CHAMP_VALUE_T (*name)(const CHAMP_KEY_T key, const CHAMP_VALUE_T old_value, void *user_data)
#define CHAMP_VALUE_EQUALSFN_T(name) int (*name)(const CHAMP_VALUE_T left, const CHAMP_VALUE_T right)


/**
 * These macros help with defining the various callbacks. Use them like so:
 * @code{c}
 * CHAMP_MAKE_EQUALSFN(equals_int, left, right)
 * {
 *     return left == right;
 * }
 * @endcode
 */

#define CHAMP_MAKE_HASHFN(name, arg_1) uint32_t name(const CHAMP_KEY_T arg_1)
#define CHAMP_MAKE_EQUALSFN(name, arg_l, arg_r) int name(const CHAMP_KEY_T arg_l, const CHAMP_KEY_T arg_r)
#define CHAMP_MAKE_ASSOCFN(name, key_arg, value_arg, user_data_arg) CHAMP_VALUE_T name(const CHAMP_KEY_T key_arg, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value_arg, void *user_data_arg)
#define CHAMP_MAKE_VALUE_EQUALSFN(name, arg_l, arg_r) int name(const CHAMP_VALUE_T arg_l, const CHAMP_VALUE_T arg_r)

// todo: replace with something like: "typedef struct champ champ;" to hide implementation details.
struct champ {
    volatile uint32_t ref_count;
    unsigned length;
    struct node *root;

    CHAMP_HASHFN_T(hash);
    CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals);
};

/**
 * Creates a new map with the given hash and equals functions. This implementation is based on the assumption that if
 * two keys are equal, their hashes must be equal as well. This is commonly known as the Java Hashcode contract.
 *
 * The reference count of a new map is zero.
 *
 * @param hash
 * @param equals
 * @return
 */
struct champ *champ_new(CHAMP_HASHFN_T(hash), CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals));

/**
 * Destroys a champ. Doesn't clean up the stored key-value-pairs.
 *
 * @param old
 */
void champ_destroy(struct champ **champ);

/**
 * Atomically increases the reference count of a map.
 *
 * @param champ
 * @return
 */
struct champ *champ_acquire(const struct champ *champ);

/**
 * Atomically decreases the reference count of a map and calls champ_destroy if it caused the count to drop to zero.
 *
 * In either case then sets the reference to NULL.
 *
 * @param champ
 */
void champ_release(struct champ **champ);

/**
 * Returns the number of entries in champ.
 *
 * @param champ
 * @return the number of entries
 */
unsigned champ_length(const struct champ *champ);

/**
 * Looks up key and sets *value_receiver to the associated value. Doesn't change value_receiver if key is not set.
 *
 * @param champ
 * @param key
 * @param found is set to 0 if key is not set
 * @return
 */
CHAMP_VALUE_T champ_get(const struct champ *champ, const CHAMP_KEY_T key, int *found);

/**
 * Returns a new map derived from champ but with key set to value.
 * If replaced is not NULL, sets it to indicate if the key is present in champ.
 *
 * Reference count of the new map is zero.
 *
 * @param champ
 * @param key
 * @param value
 * @param replaced
 * @return a new champ
 */
struct champ *champ_set(const struct champ *champ, const CHAMP_KEY_T key, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value, int *replaced);

/**
 * Returns a new map derived from champ but without a mapping for key.
 *
 * Reference count of the new map is zero.
 *
 * @param champ
 * @param key
 * @param modified
 * @return
 */
struct champ *champ_del(const struct champ *champ, const CHAMP_KEY_T key, int *modified);

/**
 * Creates a new champ with the given hash and equals functions, and inserts the given keys and values.
 * Only the first 'length' elements from keys and values are inserted.
 *
 * Reference count of the new map is zero.
 *
 * @param hash
 * @param equals
 * @param keys
 * @param values
 * @param length
 * @return
 */
struct champ *champ_of(CHAMP_HASHFN_T(hash), CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals), CHAMP_KEY_T *keys, CHAMP_VALUE_T *values, size_t length);

/**
 * Returns a new map derived from champ, but with key set to the return value of fn.
 * fn is passed the key, the current value for key, and user_data.
 * If key is not present in champ, NULL is passed in place of the key and current value.
 *
 * Reference count of the new map is zero.
 *
 * @param champ
 * @param key
 * @param fn
 * @param user_data
 * @return
 */
struct champ *champ_assoc(const struct champ *champ, const CHAMP_KEY_T key, CHAMP_ASSOCFN_T(fn), const void *user_data);

/**
 * Compares two maps for equality. A lot of short-circuiting is done on the assumption that unequal hashes
 * (for both keys and values) imply inequality. This is commonly known as the Java Hashcode contract: If two values
 * are equal, their hashes must be equal as well.
 *
 * @param left
 * @param right
 * @return
 */
int champ_equals(const struct champ *left, const struct champ *right, CHAMP_VALUE_EQUALSFN_T(value_equals));

/**
 * An iterator for champ. Meant to be put on the stack.
 */
struct champ_iter {
    int stack_level;
    unsigned element_cursor;
    unsigned element_arity;
    unsigned branch_cursor_stack[8];
    unsigned branch_arity_stack[8];
    const void *node_stack[8];
};

/**
 * Initializes an iterator with a champ.
 *
 * Example:
 * @code{.c}
 * struct champ_iter iter;
 * CHAMP_KEY_T key;
 * CHAMP_VAL_T val;
 *
 * champ_iter_init(&iter, champ);
 * while(champ_iter_next(&iter, &key, &val)) {
 *     // do something with key and value
 * }
 * @endcode
 *
 * @param iter
 * @param champ
 */
void champ_iter_init(struct champ_iter *iter, const struct champ *champ);

/**
 * Advances iter and points key_receiver and value_receiver to the next pair.
 *
 * @param iter
 * @param key_receiver
 * @param value_receiver
 * @return 0 if the end of the champ has been reached
 */
int champ_iter_next(struct champ_iter *iter, CHAMP_KEY_T *key_receiver, CHAMP_VALUE_T *value_receiver);

#endif //CHAMP_CHAMP_H
```

#### champ.c

```c
/*
 * MIT License
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2020 Samuel Vogelsanger <vogelsangersamuel@gmail.com>
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
 * copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
 * SOFTWARE.
 */

/*
 * All the ref-counting specific code was marked with a "//reference counting" comment. If you need to modify this to
 * work with your own memory policy, it is recommended to start looking at those places to understand when and where
 * memory is allocated and freed.
 */

#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdatomic.h> // reference counting
#include <string.h>

#include "champ.h"

#define champ_node_debug_fmt "node{element_arity=%u, element_map=%08x, branch_arity=%u, branch_map=%08x, ref_count=%u}"
#define champ_node_debug_args(node) node->element_arity, node->element_map, node->branch_arity, node->branch_map, node->ref_count

#define HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH 5u
#define HASH_TOTAL_WIDTH (8 * sizeof(uint32_t))

/*
 * Helper functions
 */

static unsigned bitcount(uint32_t value)
{
    // taken from http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel
    value = value - ((value >> 1u) & 0x55555555u);                    // reuse input as temporary
    value = (value & 0x33333333u) + ((value >> 2u) & 0x33333333u);     // temp
    return (((value + (value >> 4u)) & 0xF0F0F0Fu) * 0x1010101u) >> 24u;  // count
}

static uint32_t champ_mask(uint32_t hash, unsigned shift)
{
    return (hash >> shift) & ((1u << HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH) - 1);
}

static unsigned champ_index(uint32_t bitmap, uint32_t bitpos)
{
    return bitcount(bitmap & (bitpos - 1));
}

/*
 * Data structure definitions
 */

struct kv {
    CHAMP_KEY_T key;
    CHAMP_VALUE_T val;
};

#define CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T struct kv
#define CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T struct node *

struct node {
    uint8_t element_arity;
    uint8_t branch_arity;
    volatile uint16_t ref_count; // reference counting
    uint32_t element_map;
    uint32_t branch_map;
    CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T content[];
};

struct collision_node {
    uint8_t element_arity; // MUST SHARE LAYOUT WITH struct node
    uint8_t branch_arity; // MUST SHARE LAYOUT WITH struct node
    volatile uint16_t ref_count; // MUST SHARE LAYOUT WITH struct node // reference counting
    CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T content[];
};

static const struct node empty_node = {
    .branch_arity = 0,
    .element_arity = 0,
    .ref_count = 1,
    .branch_map = 0,
    .element_map = 0,
};

#define CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node) (node)->content
#define CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(node) ((CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T const *)&(node)->content[(node)->element_arity])

#define CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(length) (sizeof(CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T) * (length))
#define CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES_SIZE(length) (sizeof(CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T) * (length))

#define CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_AT(node, bitpos) CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node)[champ_index(node->element_map, bitpos)]
#define CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_AT(node, bitpos) CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(node)[champ_index(node->branch_map, bitpos)]

/*
 * static function declarations
 */

// node constructor
static struct node *node_new(uint32_t element_map, uint32_t branch_map, CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T const *elements,
                 uint8_t element_arity, CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T const *branches, uint8_t branch_arity);

// collision node variant
static struct collision_node *collision_node_new(const CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T *values, uint8_t element_arity);

// destructor
static void node_destroy(struct node *node);

// reference counting
static inline struct node *champ_node_acquire(const struct node *node);

// reference counting
static inline void champ_node_release(const struct node *node);


// top-level functions
static CHAMP_VALUE_T node_get(const struct node *node, CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals), const CHAMP_KEY_T key, uint32_t hash,
                  unsigned shift, int *found);

static struct node *node_update(const struct node *node, CHAMP_HASHFN_T(hashfn), CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                const CHAMP_KEY_T key, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value, uint32_t hash, unsigned shift,
                int *found);

static struct node *node_assoc(const struct node *node, CHAMP_HASHFN_T(hashfn), CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                   const CHAMP_KEY_T key, CHAMP_ASSOCFN_T(fn), const void *user_data, uint32_t hash,
                   unsigned shift, int *found);

static struct node *node_del(const struct node *node, CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals), const CHAMP_KEY_T key, uint32_t hash,
                 unsigned shift, int *modified);

// collision node variants
static CHAMP_VALUE_T collision_node_get(const struct collision_node *node, CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                    const CHAMP_KEY_T key, int *found);

static struct collision_node *collision_node_update(const struct collision_node *node, CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                            const CHAMP_KEY_T key, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value, int *found);

static struct collision_node *collision_node_assoc(const struct collision_node *node, CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                           const CHAMP_KEY_T key, CHAMP_ASSOCFN_T(fn), const void *user_data,
                           int *found);

static struct collision_node *collision_node_del(const struct collision_node *node, CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                         const CHAMP_KEY_T key, int *modified);


// helper functions for creation of modified nodes
static struct node *node_merge(uint32_t hash_l, const CHAMP_KEY_T key_l, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value_l, uint32_t hash_r,
                   const CHAMP_KEY_T key_r, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value_r, unsigned shift);

static struct node *node_clone_pullup(const struct node *node, uint32_t bitpos, const struct kv element);

static struct node *node_clone_update_branch(const struct node *node, uint32_t bitpos, struct node *branch);

static struct node *node_clone_pushdown(const struct node *node, uint32_t bitpos, struct node *branch);

static struct node *node_clone_insert_element(const struct node *node, uint32_t bitpos, const CHAMP_KEY_T key,
                          const CHAMP_VALUE_T value);

static struct node *node_clone_update_element(const struct node *node, uint32_t bitpos, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value);

static struct node *node_clone_remove_element(const struct node *node, uint32_t bitpos);

// collision node variants
static struct collision_node *collision_node_clone_insert_element(const struct collision_node *node,
                                  const CHAMP_KEY_T key, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value);

static struct collision_node *collision_node_clone_update_element(const struct collision_node *node, unsigned index,
                                  const CHAMP_VALUE_T value);

static struct collision_node *collision_node_clone_remove_element(const struct collision_node *node, unsigned index);


// equality
static int node_equals(const struct node *left, const struct node *right, CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(key_equals),
               CHAMP_VALUE_EQUALSFN_T(value_equals), unsigned shift);

static int collision_node_equals(const struct collision_node *left, const struct collision_node *right,
                 CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(key_equals), CHAMP_VALUE_EQUALSFN_T(value_equals));


// champ private constructor
static struct champ *champ_from(struct node *root, unsigned length, CHAMP_HASHFN_T(hash), CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals));


// iterator helper functions
static void iter_push(struct champ_iter *iterator, const struct node *node);

static void iter_pop(struct champ_iter *iterator);


/*
 * definitions
 */

static void node_destroy(struct node *node)
{
    DEBUG_PRINT("    destroying " champ_node_debug_fmt "@%p\n", champ_node_debug_args(node), (void *)node);

    // reference counting
    CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T *branches = (CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T *)CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(node);
    for (int i = 0; i < node->branch_arity; ++i) {
        champ_node_release(branches[i]);
    }

    free(node);
}

// reference counting
static inline struct node *champ_node_acquire(const struct node *node)
{
    if (node == &empty_node)
        return (struct node *)node;
    atomic_fetch_add((uint16_t *)&node->ref_count, 1u);
    return (struct node *)node;
}

// reference counting
static inline void champ_node_release(const struct node *node)
{
    if (node == &empty_node)
        return;
    if (atomic_fetch_sub((uint16_t *)&node->ref_count, 1u) == 1)
        node_destroy((struct node *)node);
}

/**
 * WARNING: all branches in <code>branches</code> are "acquired", i.e. their reference count is incremented.
 * Do not pass an "almost correct" list of branches.
 */
static struct node *node_new(uint32_t element_map, uint32_t branch_map,
                 CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T const *elements, uint8_t element_arity,
                 CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T const *branches, uint8_t branch_arity)
{
    const size_t content_size = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(element_arity) + CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES_SIZE(branch_arity);
    struct node *result = malloc(sizeof(*result) + content_size);

    result->element_arity = element_arity;
    result->branch_arity = branch_arity;
    result->ref_count = 0;
    result->element_map = element_map;
    result->branch_map = branch_map;

    memcpy(CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(result), elements, CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(element_arity));

    CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T *branches_dest = (CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T *)CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(result);
    // reference counting
    for (int i = 0; i < branch_arity; ++i) {
        branches_dest[i] = champ_node_acquire(branches[i]);
    }

    return result;
}

static CHAMP_VALUE_T collision_node_get(const struct collision_node *node, CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                    const CHAMP_KEY_T key, int *found)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < node->element_arity; ++i) {
        struct kv kv = node->content[i];
        if (equals(kv.key, key)) {
            *found = 1;
            return kv.val;
        }
    }

    *found = 0;
    return (CHAMP_VALUE_T)0;
}

static CHAMP_VALUE_T node_get(const struct node *node, CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                  const CHAMP_KEY_T key, uint32_t hash, unsigned shift, int *found)
{
    if (shift >= HASH_TOTAL_WIDTH)
        return collision_node_get((const struct collision_node *)node, equals, key, found);

    const uint32_t bitpos = 1u << champ_mask(hash, shift);

    if (node->branch_map & bitpos) {
        return node_get(CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_AT(node, bitpos), equals, key, hash, shift + HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH, found);

    } else if (node->element_map & bitpos) {
        CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T kv = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_AT(node, bitpos);
        if (equals(kv.key, key)) {
            *found = 1;
            return kv.val;
        }
    }


    *found = 0;
    return (CHAMP_VALUE_T)0;
}

static struct node *node_clone_insert_element(const struct node *node, uint32_t bitpos,
                          const CHAMP_KEY_T key, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value)
{
    CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T elements[1u << HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH];
    const unsigned index = champ_index(node->element_map, bitpos);

    // copy <branch_arity> chunks in total
    memcpy(elements, CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node), CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(index)); // copy first <index> chunks
    elements[index].key = (CHAMP_KEY_T)key;
    elements[index].val = (CHAMP_VALUE_T)value;
    memcpy(
        &elements[index + 1], // start copying into one-past-<index>
        &CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node)[index], // start copying from <index>
        CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(node->element_arity - index) // <index> chunks already copied, <branch_arity> - <index> remaining
    );

    return node_new(
        node->element_map | bitpos, node->branch_map, elements,
        node->element_arity + 1, CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(node), node->branch_arity);
}

static struct node *node_clone_update_element(const struct node *node,
                          uint32_t bitpos, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value)
{
    CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T elements[1u << HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH];
    const unsigned index = champ_index(node->element_map, bitpos);

    memcpy(elements, CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node), CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(node->element_arity));
    elements[index].val = (CHAMP_VALUE_T)value;
    return node_new(node->element_map, node->branch_map, elements, node->element_arity, CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(node), node->branch_arity);
}

static struct node *node_clone_update_branch(const struct node *node,
                         uint32_t bitpos, struct node *branch)
{
    CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T branches[1u << HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH];
    const unsigned index = champ_index(node->branch_map, bitpos);

    memcpy(branches, CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(node), CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES_SIZE(node->branch_arity));
    branches[index] = branch;
    return node_new(node->element_map, node->branch_map, CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node), node->element_arity, branches, node->branch_arity);
}

static struct node *node_clone_pushdown(const struct node *node,
                    uint32_t bitpos, struct node *branch)
{
    CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T elements[1u << HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH];
    CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T branches[1u << HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH];
    const unsigned element_index = champ_index(node->element_map, bitpos);
    const unsigned branch_index = champ_index(node->branch_map, bitpos);

    memcpy(elements, CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node), CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(element_index));
    memcpy(
        &elements[element_index],
        &CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node)[element_index + 1],
        CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(node->element_arity - (element_index + 1))
    );

    memcpy(branches, CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(node), CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES_SIZE(branch_index));
    memcpy(
        &branches[branch_index + 1],
        &CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(node)[branch_index],
        CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES_SIZE(node->branch_arity - branch_index)
    );
    branches[branch_index] = branch;

    return node_new(
        node->element_map & ~bitpos,
        node->branch_map | bitpos, elements, node->element_arity - 1, branches, node->branch_arity + 1);
}

static struct collision_node *collision_node_new(const CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T *values, uint8_t element_arity)
{
    size_t content_size = sizeof(CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T) * element_arity;
    struct collision_node *result = malloc(sizeof(*result) + content_size);

    result->element_arity = element_arity;
    result->branch_arity = 0;
    result->ref_count = 0;

    memcpy(result->content, values, CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(element_arity));

    return result;
}

static struct node *node_merge(uint32_t hash_l, const CHAMP_KEY_T key_l, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value_l,
                   uint32_t hash_r, const CHAMP_KEY_T key_r, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value_r,
                   unsigned shift)
{
    uint32_t bitpos_l = 1u << champ_mask(hash_l, shift);
    uint32_t bitpos_r = 1u << champ_mask(hash_r, shift);

    if (shift >= HASH_TOTAL_WIDTH) {
        CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T elements[2];
        elements[0].key = (CHAMP_KEY_T)key_l;
        elements[0].val = (CHAMP_VALUE_T)value_l;
        elements[1].key = (CHAMP_KEY_T)key_r;
        elements[1].val = (CHAMP_VALUE_T)value_r;

        return (struct node *)collision_node_new(elements, 2);

    } else if (bitpos_l != bitpos_r) {
        CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T elements[2];

        if (bitpos_l <= bitpos_r) {
            elements[0].key = (CHAMP_KEY_T)key_l;
            elements[0].val = (CHAMP_VALUE_T)value_l;
            elements[1].key = (CHAMP_KEY_T)key_r;
            elements[1].val = (CHAMP_VALUE_T)value_r;
        } else {
            elements[0].key = (CHAMP_KEY_T)key_r;
            elements[0].val = (CHAMP_VALUE_T)value_r;
            elements[1].key = (CHAMP_KEY_T)key_l;
            elements[1].val = (CHAMP_VALUE_T)value_l;
        }

        return node_new(bitpos_l | bitpos_r, 0u, elements, 2, NULL, 0);

    } else {
        struct node *sub_node = node_merge(
            hash_l,
            key_l,
            value_l,
            hash_r,
            key_r,
            value_r,
            shift + HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH
        );

        return node_new(0, bitpos_l, NULL, 0, &sub_node, 1);
    }
}

static struct collision_node *collision_node_clone_update_element(const struct collision_node *node,
                                  unsigned index, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value)
{
    CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T elements[node->element_arity];

    memcpy(elements, node->content, CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(node->element_arity));
    elements[index].val = (CHAMP_VALUE_T)value;

    return collision_node_new(elements, node->element_arity);
}

static struct collision_node *collision_node_clone_insert_element(const struct collision_node *node,
                                  const CHAMP_KEY_T key,
                                  const CHAMP_VALUE_T value)
{
    CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T elements[node->element_arity + 1];

    memcpy(elements, node->content, CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(node->element_arity));
    elements[node->element_arity].key = (CHAMP_KEY_T)key;
    elements[node->element_arity].val = (CHAMP_VALUE_T)value;

    return collision_node_new(elements, node->element_arity + 1);
}

static struct collision_node *collision_node_update(const struct collision_node *node,
                            CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                            const CHAMP_KEY_T key, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value,
                            int *found)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < node->element_arity; ++i) {
        struct kv kv = node->content[i];
        if (equals(kv.key, key)) {
            *found = 1;

            return collision_node_clone_update_element(node, i, value);
        }
    }

    return collision_node_clone_insert_element(node, key, value);
}

static struct node *node_update(const struct node *node, CHAMP_HASHFN_T(hashfn), CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                const CHAMP_KEY_T key, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value, uint32_t hash, unsigned shift,
                int *found)
{
    if (shift >= HASH_TOTAL_WIDTH)
        return (struct node *)collision_node_update((const struct collision_node *)node, equals, key, value, found);

    const uint32_t bitpos = 1u << champ_mask(hash, shift);

    if (node->branch_map & bitpos) {
        const struct node *sub_node = CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_AT(node, bitpos);
        struct node *new_sub_node = node_update(sub_node, hashfn, equals, key, value, hash,
            shift + HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH, found);
        return node_clone_update_branch(node, bitpos, new_sub_node);

    } else if (node->element_map & bitpos) {
        const CHAMP_KEY_T current_key = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_AT(node, bitpos).key;

        if (equals(current_key, key)) {
            *found = 1;
            return node_clone_update_element(node, bitpos, value);

        } else {
            const CHAMP_VALUE_T current_value = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_AT(node, bitpos).val;
            struct node *sub_node = node_merge(
                hashfn(current_key),
                current_key,
                current_value,
                hashfn(key),
                key,
                value,
                shift + HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH
            );
            return node_clone_pushdown(node, bitpos, sub_node);
        }

    } else {
        return node_clone_insert_element(node, bitpos, key, value);
    }
}

static struct node *node_clone_remove_element(const struct node *node, uint32_t bitpos)
{
    DEBUG_PRINT("removing element with bit position 0x%x\n", bitpos);

    CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T elements[1u << HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH];
    const unsigned index = champ_index(node->element_map, bitpos);

    memcpy(elements, CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node), CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(index));
    memcpy(
        &elements[index],
        &CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node)[index + 1],
        CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(node->element_arity - (index + 1))
    );

    return node_new(
        node->element_map & ~bitpos, node->branch_map, elements,
        node->element_arity - 1, CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(node), node->branch_arity);
}

/*
 * 'Pullup' is the inverse of pushdown.
 * It's the process of 'pulling an entry up' from a branch, inlining it as an element instead.
 */
static struct node *node_clone_pullup(const struct node *node, uint32_t bitpos,
                      const struct kv element)
{
    CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T branches[1u << HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH];
    CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T elements[1u << HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH];
    const unsigned branch_index = champ_index(node->branch_map, bitpos);
    const unsigned element_index = champ_index(node->element_map, bitpos);

    memcpy(branches, CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(node), CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES_SIZE(branch_index));
    memcpy(
        &branches[branch_index],
        &CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(node)[branch_index + 1],
        CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES_SIZE(node->branch_arity - (branch_index + 1))
    );

    memcpy(elements, CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node), CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(element_index));
    elements[element_index] = element;
    memcpy(
        &elements[element_index + 1],
        &CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node)[element_index],
        CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(node->element_arity - element_index)
    );

    return node_new(
        node->element_map | bitpos,
        node->branch_map & ~bitpos, elements, node->element_arity + 1, branches, node->branch_arity - 1);
}

static struct collision_node *collision_node_clone_remove_element(const struct collision_node *node,
                                  unsigned index)
{
    CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T elements[node->element_arity - 1];

    memcpy(elements, node->content, CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(index));
    memcpy(elements, &node->content[index + 1], CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS_SIZE(node->element_arity - (index + 1)));

    return collision_node_new(elements, node->element_arity - 1);
}

/**
 * If only one element remains, the returned node will be passed up the tree - to where knowledge of hash collision
 * nodes is inappropriate. In that case, this will return a normal <code>struct node *</code> instead.
 *
 * Consider the only(!) place where this is called: at the start of node_del, if the hash is exhausted. The returned
 * value is then immediately returned to the previous call of node_del, where it is evaluated as new_sub_node of
 * type struct node, and its members branch_arity and element_arity are evaluated. this requires us to have those
 * members be at the exact same place in both struct node and struct collision_node.
 *
 * @return
 */
static struct collision_node *collision_node_del(const struct collision_node *node,
                         CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals), const CHAMP_KEY_T key,
                         int *modified)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < node->element_arity; ++i) {
        struct kv kv = node->content[i];
        if (equals(kv.key, key)) {
            *modified = 1;
            if (node->element_arity == 2) {
                CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T elements[1] = {node->content[i ? 0 : 1]};
                return (struct collision_node *)node_new(0, 0, elements, 1, NULL, 0);

            } else {
                return collision_node_clone_remove_element(node, i);
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

static struct node *node_del(const struct node *node, CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                 const CHAMP_KEY_T key, uint32_t hash, unsigned shift, int *modified)
{
    if (shift >= HASH_TOTAL_WIDTH)
        return (struct node *)collision_node_del((const struct collision_node *)node, equals, key, modified);

    const uint32_t bitpos = 1u << champ_mask(hash, shift);

    if (node->element_map & bitpos) {
        if (equals(CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_AT(node, bitpos).key, key)) {
            *modified = 1;
            if (node->element_arity + node->branch_arity == 1) // only possible for the root node
                return (struct node *)&empty_node;
            else
                return node_clone_remove_element(node, bitpos);
        } else {
            return NULL; // returning from node_del with *modified == 0 means abort immediately
        }

    } else if (node->branch_map & bitpos) {
        struct node *sub_node = CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_AT(node, bitpos);
        struct node *new_sub_node = node_del(sub_node, equals, key, hash,
            shift + HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH, modified);

        if (!*modified)
            return NULL; // returning from node_del with *modified == 0 means abort immediately

        if (node->branch_arity + node->element_arity == 1) { // node is a 'passthrough'
            if (new_sub_node->branch_arity * 2 + new_sub_node->element_arity == 1) { // new_sub_node is non-canonical, propagate for inlining
                new_sub_node->element_map = bitpos;
                return new_sub_node;
            } else { // canonical, bubble modified trie to the top
                return node_clone_update_branch(node, bitpos, new_sub_node);
            }

        } else if (new_sub_node->branch_arity * 2 + new_sub_node->element_arity == 1) { // new_sub_node is non-canonical
            const struct kv remaining_element = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(new_sub_node)[0];
            node_destroy(new_sub_node);
            return node_clone_pullup(node, bitpos, remaining_element);

        } else { // both node and new_sub_node are canonical
            return node_clone_update_branch(node, bitpos, new_sub_node);
        }

    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

static struct collision_node *collision_node_assoc(const struct collision_node *node,
                           CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                           const CHAMP_KEY_T key, CHAMP_ASSOCFN_T(fn),
                           const void *user_data,
                           int *found)
{
    CHAMP_VALUE_T new_value;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < node->element_arity; ++i) {
        struct kv kv = node->content[i];
        if (equals(kv.key, key)) {
            *found = 1;
            CHAMP_VALUE_T old_value = kv.val;
            new_value = fn(key, old_value, (void *)user_data);
            return collision_node_clone_update_element(node, i, new_value);
        }
    }

    new_value = fn((CHAMP_KEY_T)0, (CHAMP_VALUE_T)0, (void *)user_data);
    return collision_node_clone_insert_element(node, key, new_value);
}

static struct node *node_assoc(const struct node *node, CHAMP_HASHFN_T(hashfn), CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
                   const CHAMP_KEY_T key, CHAMP_ASSOCFN_T(fn), const void *user_data, uint32_t hash,
                   unsigned shift, int *found)
{
    if (shift >= HASH_TOTAL_WIDTH)
        return (struct node *)collision_node_assoc((const struct collision_node *)node, equals, key, fn, user_data, found);

    const uint32_t bitpos = 1u << champ_mask(hash, shift);

    if (node->branch_map & bitpos) {
        const struct node *sub_node = CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_AT(node, bitpos);
        struct node *new_sub_node = node_assoc(sub_node, hashfn, equals, key, fn, user_data, hash,
            shift + HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH, found);
        return node_clone_update_branch(node, bitpos, new_sub_node);

    } else if (node->element_map & bitpos) {
        const CHAMP_KEY_T current_key = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_AT(node, bitpos).key;

        if (equals(current_key, key)) {
            *found = 1;
            const CHAMP_VALUE_T old_value = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_AT(node, bitpos).val;
            CHAMP_VALUE_T new_value = fn(key, old_value, (void *)user_data);
            return node_clone_update_element(node, bitpos, new_value);

        } else {
            const CHAMP_VALUE_T current_value = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_AT(node, bitpos).val;
            const CHAMP_VALUE_T new_value = fn((CHAMP_KEY_T)0, (CHAMP_VALUE_T)0, (void *)user_data);
            struct node *sub_node = node_merge(
                hashfn(current_key),
                current_key,
                current_value,
                hash,
                key,
                new_value,
                shift + HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH
            );
            return node_clone_pushdown(node, bitpos, sub_node);
        }

    } else {
        const CHAMP_VALUE_T value = fn((CHAMP_KEY_T)0, (CHAMP_VALUE_T)0, (void *)user_data);
        return node_clone_insert_element(node, bitpos, key, value);
    }
}

static int collision_node_equals(const struct collision_node *left, const struct collision_node *right,
                 CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(key_equals), CHAMP_VALUE_EQUALSFN_T(value_equals))
{
    if (left == right)
        return 1;
    if (left->element_arity != right->element_arity)
        return 0;


    for (unsigned left_i = 0; left_i < left->element_arity; ++left_i) {
        struct kv left_element = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(left)[left_i];

        for (unsigned right_i = 0; right_i < right->element_arity; ++right_i) {
            struct kv right_element = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(right)[right_i];

            if (key_equals(left_element.key, right_element.key) && value_equals(left_element.val, right_element.val))
                goto found_matching_element;
        }
        return 0; // compared left_element to all elements in right node, no match.

        found_matching_element:
        continue;
    }
    return 1; // compared all elements in left node, never had an element without match.
}

static int node_equals(const struct node *left, const struct node *right, CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(key_equals),
               CHAMP_VALUE_EQUALSFN_T(value_equals), unsigned shift)
{
    if (shift >= HASH_TOTAL_WIDTH)
        return collision_node_equals((struct collision_node *)left, (struct collision_node *)right, key_equals, value_equals);
    if (left == right)
        return 1;
    if (left->element_map != right->element_map)
        return 0;
    if (left->branch_map != right->branch_map)
        return 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < left->element_arity; ++i) {
        struct kv left_element = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(left)[i];
        struct kv right_element = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(right)[i];
        if (!key_equals(left_element.key, right_element.key) || !value_equals(left_element.val, right_element.val))
            return 0;
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < left->branch_arity; ++i) {
        struct node *left_branch = CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(left)[i];
        struct node *right_branch = CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(right)[i];
        if (!node_equals(left_branch, right_branch, key_equals, value_equals, shift + HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}


static struct champ *champ_from(struct node *root, unsigned length,
                CHAMP_HASHFN_T(hash), CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals))
{
    struct champ *result = malloc(sizeof(*result));
    result->ref_count = 0;
    result->root = root;
    result->length = length;
    result->hash = hash;
    result->equals = equals;
    return result;
}

void champ_destroy(struct champ **champ)
{
    DEBUG_PRINT("destroying champ@%p\n", (void *)*champ);
    champ_node_release((*champ)->root);
    free(*champ);
    *champ = NULL;
}

struct champ *champ_new(CHAMP_HASHFN_T(hash), CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals))
{
    return champ_from((struct node *)&empty_node, 0, hash, equals);
}

struct champ *champ_acquire(const struct champ *champ)
{
    atomic_fetch_add((uint32_t *)&champ->ref_count, 1u);
    return (struct champ *)champ;
}

void champ_release(struct champ **champ)
{
    if (atomic_fetch_sub((uint32_t *)&((*champ)->ref_count), 1u) == 1u)
        champ_destroy((struct champ **)champ);
    *champ = NULL;
}

struct champ *champ_of(CHAMP_HASHFN_T(hash), CHAMP_EQUALSFN_T(equals),
               CHAMP_KEY_T*keys, CHAMP_VALUE_T*values, size_t length)
{
    struct champ *result = champ_new(hash, equals);
    while (length--) {
        struct champ *tmp = champ_set(result, keys[length], values[length], NULL);
        champ_destroy(&result);
        result = tmp;
    }
    return result;
}

unsigned champ_length(const struct champ *champ)
{
    return champ->length;
}

struct champ *champ_set(const struct champ *champ,
            const CHAMP_KEY_T key, const CHAMP_VALUE_T value, int *replaced)
{
    const uint32_t hash = champ->hash(key);
    int found = 0;
    int *found_p = replaced ? replaced : &found;
    *found_p = 0;
    struct node *new_root = champ_node_acquire(node_update(champ->root, champ->hash, champ->equals, key, value, hash, 0, found_p));
    return champ_from(new_root, champ->length + (*found_p ? 0 : 1), champ->hash, champ->equals);
}

CHAMP_VALUE_T champ_get(const struct champ *champ, const CHAMP_KEY_T key, int *found)
{
    uint32_t hash = champ->hash(key);
    int tmp = 0;
    return node_get(champ->root, champ->equals, key, hash, 0, found ? found : &tmp);
}

struct champ *champ_del(const struct champ *champ, const CHAMP_KEY_T key, int *modified)
{
    const uint32_t hash = champ->hash(key);
    int found = 0;
    int *found_p = modified ? modified : &found;
    *found_p = 0;
    struct node *new_root = node_del(champ->root, champ->equals, key, hash, 0, found_p);
    if (!*found_p)
        return (struct champ *)champ;
    return champ_from(champ_node_acquire(new_root), champ->length - 1, champ->hash, champ->equals);
}

struct champ *champ_assoc(const struct champ *champ, const CHAMP_KEY_T key, CHAMP_ASSOCFN_T(fn), const void *user_data)
{
    const uint32_t hash = champ->hash(key);
    int found = 0;
    struct node *new_root = champ_node_acquire(node_assoc(champ->root, champ->hash, champ->equals, key, fn, user_data, hash, 0, &found));
    return champ_from(new_root, champ->length + (found ? 0 : 1), champ->hash, champ->equals);
}

int champ_equals(const struct champ *left, const struct champ *right, CHAMP_VALUE_EQUALSFN_T(value_equals))
{
    if (left == right)
        return 1;
    else if (champ_length(left) != champ_length(right))
        return 0;
    else
        return node_equals(left->root, right->root, left->equals, value_equals, 0);
}

static const char *indent(unsigned level)
{
    const char *spaces = "                                                                                ";
    return spaces + 4 * (20 - level);
}

#define iprintf(level, fmt, ...) printf("%s" fmt, indent(level), ##__VA_ARGS__)

static char *format_binary(uint32_t value, char *buffer)
{
    for (char *pos = buffer + 31; pos >= buffer; --pos) {
        if (value & 1u) *pos = '1';
        else *pos = '0';
        value = value >> 1u;
    }
    return buffer;
}

static void champ_node_repr(const struct node *node, const char *kp, const char *vp, unsigned shift, unsigned i_level)
{
    if (shift >= HASH_TOTAL_WIDTH) {
        iprintf(i_level, "\"collision node (omitted)\"");
        return;
    }
    char map_buf[33];
    printf("{\n");
    iprintf(i_level, "\"element_map\": 0b%.32s,\n", format_binary(node->element_map, map_buf));
    iprintf(i_level, "\"element_arity\": %u,\n", node->element_arity);
    iprintf(i_level, "\"branch_map\": 0b%.32s,\n", format_binary(node->branch_map, map_buf));
    iprintf(i_level, "\"branch_arity\": %u,\n", node->branch_arity);
    iprintf(i_level, "\"elements\": {\n");
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < node->element_arity; ++i) {
        CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENT_T el = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(node)[i];
        iprintf(i_level + 1, "\"");
        printf(kp, el.key);
        printf("\": ");
        printf(vp, el.val);
        printf(",\n");
    }
    iprintf(i_level, "},\n");
    iprintf(i_level, "\"nodes\": [\n");
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < node->branch_arity; ++i) {
        CHAMP_NODE_BRANCH_T n = CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(node)[i];
        iprintf(i_level + 1, "");
        champ_node_repr(n, kp, vp, shift + HASH_PARTITION_WIDTH, i_level + 2);
        printf(",\n");
    }
    iprintf(i_level, "],\n");
    iprintf(i_level - 1, "}");
}

void champ_repr(const struct champ *champ, const char *key_prefix, const char *value_prefix)
{
    printf("{\n");
    iprintf(1, "\"length\": %d,\n", champ->length);
    iprintf(1, "\"root\": ");
    champ_node_repr(champ->root, key_prefix, value_prefix, 0, 2);
    printf("\n}\n");
}

void champ_iter_init(struct champ_iter *iterator, const struct champ *champ)
{
    iterator->stack_level = 0;
    iterator->element_cursor = 0;
    iterator->element_arity = champ->root->element_arity;
    iterator->branch_cursor_stack[0] = 0;
    iterator->branch_arity_stack[0] = champ->root->branch_arity;
    iterator->node_stack[0] = champ->root;
}

static void iter_push(struct champ_iter *iterator, const struct node *node)
{
    iterator->stack_level += 1;
    iterator->element_cursor = 0;
    iterator->element_arity = node->element_arity;
    iterator->branch_cursor_stack[iterator->stack_level] = 0;
    iterator->branch_arity_stack[iterator->stack_level] = node->branch_arity;
    iterator->node_stack[iterator->stack_level] = node;
}

static void iter_pop(struct champ_iter *iterator)
{
    iterator->stack_level -= 1;
}

int champ_iter_next(struct champ_iter *iterator, CHAMP_KEY_T *key, CHAMP_VALUE_T *value)
{
    if (iterator->stack_level == -1)
        return 0;

    const struct node *current_node = iterator->node_stack[iterator->stack_level];
    unsigned *branch_cursor = iterator->branch_cursor_stack + iterator->stack_level;
    if (*branch_cursor == 0 && iterator->element_cursor < current_node->element_arity) { // todo: write test for this
        *key = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(current_node)[iterator->element_cursor].key;
        *value = CHAMP_NODE_ELEMENTS(current_node)[iterator->element_cursor].val;
        ++iterator->element_cursor;
        return 1;

    } else {
        if (*branch_cursor < iterator->branch_arity_stack[iterator->stack_level]) {
            iter_push(iterator, CHAMP_NODE_BRANCHES(current_node)[*branch_cursor]);
            ++*branch_cursor;
            return champ_iter_next(iterator, key, value);

        } else {
            iter_pop(iterator);
            return champ_iter_next(iterator, key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

### Using it as a "`champ<string,int>`"

This is an example of how to use this map with a scalar value type.

Compile with `gcc -DDEBUG -O3 -o main main.c str_int_map.c -std=c11`

#### champ_str_int.h

```c
#define CHAMP_KEY_T char*
#define CHAMP_VALUE_T int
#include "champ.h"
```

#### champ_str_int.c

```c
#include "str_int_map.h"
#include "champ.c"
```

#### main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "str_int_map.h"
#include "champ_fns.h"

int equals_str(const char *l, const char *r) {
    return !strcmp(l, r);
}

uint32_t hash_str(const char *str) {
    uint32_t hash = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        hash = 31 * hash + (uint32_t)str[i];
    }
    return hash;
}

int main()
{
    struct champ *map = champ_acquire(champ_new(hash_str, equals_str));
    // note: key is char* and value is int instead of void*, no cast required
    map = champ_set(map, "answer", 42, NULL);
    printf("answer == %d\n", champ_get(map, "answer", NULL));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without digging into it too deeply, this seems well put-together and it's clear that you know what you're doing. The only minor thing I picked up on first read is that this:

```
int *found
```

should be using `<stdbool.h>` instead of an `int`; mostly to help your users understand what's happening. The same goes for the return value of `equals_str`.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying pretty hard. And yeah, I was under the impression that `int` is the de-facto `bool` in C and nobody really uses `<stdbool>`, but my teachers just might have been a bit quirky.